# CAS login/redirect not working because of http/https conflict

Tags: tomcat, maven, https, cas

I have a CAS server, mostly still default, running on http via port:8080, and https via port:8008

The production environment is CAS 3.4.11, tomcat 5, and is using maven2 deployment

When someone logs in, and we try to navigate the CAS site to something like `https://mydomain:8008/cas/services/manage.html` to verify their login it redirects them to:
`HTTP://mydomain:8008/cas/login`

Tomcat is configured to serve up https ONLY on port 8008, causing the unsuspecting browser to receive an encrypted byte stream via http and offers it to the user as a download.

I'm new to CAS, and I know somewhere in the configs is the option to use HTTPS in the redirects as opposed to http but I have not found it yet.

When your answer, PLEASE, I am tired of CAS documentation sites and blogs that say p:client-use-https="true" as their entire explanation. I need file, section/subsection, bean, and other relevant info to best practices.

I also recognize that tomcat, which I have never worked with before, could be configured to refuse/redirect http requests to https on a select port. Preferably I would like to enact both solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the file tomcat/webapps/cas/WEB-INF/cas.properties has a server.prefix that if it is proceded by http://, will force http at the begining of all Location: headers. likewise, using https will force it to include that instead.

Tomcat has the connector port defintion:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector port="8080"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

the redirectionPort actually implies IF HTTPS is needed, send here and I have to change it to match the SSL port I configured at 8009